# How to get HTML element that is before a certain class?

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest, xml2

I'm scraping and having trouble getting the element of the “th” tag that comes before the other “th” element that contains the “type2” class. I prefer to take it by identifying that it is the element "th" before the "th" with class "type2" because my HTML has a lot of "th" and that was the only difference I found between the tables.

Using rvest or xml2 (or other R package), can I get this parent?
The content which I want is "text_that_I_want".

Thank you!

```
<tr>
    <th class="array">text_that_I_want</th>
    <td class="array">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="string type2">name</th>
                    <th class="array type2">answers</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
```

Comment: Is this coming from a publicly viewable webpage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formal and more generalizable way to navigate xpath relative to a given node is via `ancestor` `preceding-sibling`:

```
read_html(htmldoc) %>% 
html_nodes(xpath = "//th[@class = 'string type2']/ancestor::td/preceding-sibling::th") %>% 
html_text()
#> [1] "text_that_I_want"
```

Comment: Nice! Didn't know that :)

Comment: Interesting solution, but it didn't work properly, because it do need to consider the 'type2' class. If it doesn't consider the 'type2' class, it will also get th wrong content

Answer (score 1):

We can look for the "type2" string in all `<th>`s, get the index of the first occurrence and substract 1 to get the index we want:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

location <- test%>% 
  html_nodes('th') %>% 
  str_detect("type2")

index_want <- min(which(location == TRUE) - 1)

test%>% 
  html_nodes('th') %>%
  .[[index_want]] %>% 
  html_text()

[1] "text_that_I_want"
```