# How to get HTML element considering later content of another tag and not the class?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, xml2

I am transforming HTML into a beautiful and tidy CSV. I have a file full of tables and with few classes. I have three types of tables, and their structure is the same. The only difference is the content within the "th" element which comes after the element in which I am interested. How can I get only the content of the tables that have certain text in "th" ("text_that_I_want_to_get")? Is there a way to insert a class with R inside each type of table?

Type 1 of table

```
 <tr>
    <th class="array">text_that_I_want_to_get</th>
    <td class="array">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="string">name</th>
                    <th class="string">mean</th>
                    <th class="string">stdev</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
```

Type 2 of table

```
<tr>
    <th class="array">text_that_I_want_to_get</th>
    <td class="array">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="string">name</th>
                    <th class="array">answers</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
```

Type 3 of table

```
<tr>
    <th class="array">text_that_I_want_to_get</th>
    <td class="array">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="string">Reference</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
```

Comment: Are the html code chucks character objects in R? if so you could try `sub(".*<th class="array">(.*)</th>.*","\\1", My_HTML_String)`

Comment: I don't think that it would work properly. I am not interested only in the content inside the "th" (text_that_I_want_to_get), but also in the content after the tbody (which is huge and that's why I didn't post it)... And there are plenty of tables such as these and I don't have their position in the HTML

Comment: You should post your desired output. It is unclear what you are trying to extract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the following three xpaths:

```
xpath1 <- "//td[table[./thead/tr/th/text() = 'stdev']]/preceding-sibling::th"
xpath2 <- "//td[table[./thead/tr/th/text() = 'answers']]/preceding-sibling::th"
xpath3 <- "//td[table[./thead/tr/th/text() = 'Reference']]/preceding-sibling::th"
```

These find the `td` node that is at the root of each of the three table types, then locate the preceding `th` sibling with the text you want.

So to get "text_that_I_want_to_get" for table type 1, you do:

```
read_html(url) %>% html_nodes(xpath = xpath1) %>% html_text()
#> [1] "text_that_I_want_to_get"
```

And you can do the same with `xpath2` and `xpath3` to get text from table type 2 and table type 3.

Comment: My goal is actually to get the text inside the "th" (text_that_I_want_to_get), so I can not write it inside xpath1. Besides this, the tables of each type need to be separated. For example, at the first time, I will get only all type 1 tables.

Comment: @polo in that case how is this any different from the other question of yours that I answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62390373/how-to-get-html-element-that-is-before-a-certain-class  except you use `@class = 'string' `in the xpath?

Comment: It's different, because at that time I had to add the classes "type1", "type2" and "type3" manually to my HTML. I could add the classes, because the content inside "th" is different in each type (name, mean, stdev for type1; name, answers for type2; Reference for type3). My goal is not to open the HTML manually and correct everything in R

Comment: @polo so do you need code that identifies which table type you are dealing with and inserts `class = "type1"` or `class = "type 2"` etc in the table tag?

Comment: Yes, it could insert the class "type1" or "type2" or "type3" considering the "th" (name, mean, stdev for type1; name, answers for type2; Reference for type3). Or it could get the "th" (text_that_I_want_to_get) considering the following "th" (name, mean, stdev for type1; name, answers for type2; Reference for type3)

Comment: @polo I have added a substantial edit which hopefully does what you need.

Comment: Thank you for your update. After adding the class, the idea was to get the content inside the first "th" ("text_that_I_want_to_get") and not to download the HTML. But for now the code also didn't work here...

Comment: @polo so do you need to write the classes or would you be happy to just get the text, or do both? It's not clear why you need to write classes to the tables if you're not saving the html anywhere. The code above works for my example and for your given example. Maybe you can share the actual HTML or url you are trying to scrape? I can certainly do it, but not with the information you have given here.

Comment: I would be happy to just get the text, but it need to consider the "th" (name, mean, stdev for type1; name, answers for type2; Reference for type3). Or it would insert the class with the goal to get the text inside the first "th" of each type

Comment: @polo I understand. You don't need to write the class into the table to do this. You just need xpaths that identify the correct table types and work backwards to the `th` . See my update.

Comment: If this doesn't work, then you'll need to update to show the actual html, since this works for your examples.